# Matching records between EventA and the first EventB before the next EventA, in a specific order

Tags: sql, mysql, gaps-and-islands

I have the following data ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e51fc/29)),

| id | datec | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **2022-09-19 12:16:38** | **EVENTA** |
| 2 | **2022-09-19 12:16:38** | **A** |
| 3 | **2022-09-19 12:21:08** | **B** |
| 4 | **2022-09-19 12:21:12** | **EVENTD** |
| 5 | 2022-09-19 12:25:18 | C |
| 6 | 2022-09-19 12:25:18 | D |
| 7 | 2022-09-19 12:25:28 | E |
| 8 | 2022-09-19 12:25:29 | F |
| 9 | **2022-09-19 12:25:38** | **EVENTA** |
| 10 | **2022-09-19 12:25:39** | **G** |
| 11 | **2022-09-19 12:25:40** | **H** |
| 12 | **2022-09-19 12:25:48** | **I** |
| 13 | **2022-09-19 12:27:18** | **EVENTD** |
| 14 | 2022-09-19 12:29:08 | J |

I can't figure out how to select values between two others, but in a specific order. Only events **between EVENTA and EVENTD** should be returned, in that order.

So that results should be the rows with id **1** to **4** and **9** to **13**

Tried to do something like the following, but it is giving me id 1,4,9 and 13 omitting what is between them.

```
SELECT id, datec, event 
FROM table1 
WHERE event BETWEEN 'EVENTA' AND 'EVENTD';
```

I then tried to use this,

```
SELECT id, datec, event 
FROM table1 
WHERE (id BETWEEN (SELECT id 
                   FROM table1 
                   WHERE event BETWEEN 'EVENTA' AND 'EVENTD' 
                   LIMIT 1) 
              AND (SELECT id 
                   FROM table1 
                   WHERE event BETWEEN 'EVENTA' AND 'EVENTD' 
                   LIMIT 1,1)) 
   OR (id BETWEEN (SELECT id 
                   FROM table1 
                   WHERE event BETWEEN 'EVENTA' AND 'EVENTD' 
                   LIMIT 2,1) 
              AND (SELECT id 
                   FROM table1 
                   WHERE event BETWEEN 'EVENTA' AND 'EVENTD' LIMIT 3,1));
```

And it gives me the results but I have many rows in my table.

Can please someone guide me on how to repeat this till the end as i'm sure there is a way to do this but i can't figure out how?

Regards,

pierre

Comment: What is the exact output you want here?

Comment: Thanks for having a look. 
Ideally, what is in bold or in fiddle. 

`1 2022-09-19T12:16:38Z EVENTA
2 2022-09-19T12:16:38Z A
3 2022-09-19T12:21:08Z B
4 2022-09-19T12:21:12Z EVENTD
9 2022-09-19T12:25:38Z EVENTA
10 2022-09-19T12:25:39Z G
11 2022-09-19T12:25:40Z H
12 2022-09-19T12:25:48Z I
13 2022-09-19T12:27:18Z EVENTD`

Comment: Is there always alternation between an EventA and an EventD event? Or is it possible to expect a sequence of events like `EventA, G, H, EventA, EventA, J, K, EventD, EventD, EventD`? And if this last one is a potential case, what's the corresponding expected output?

Comment: Are there any records where `datec` really have the same exact value?

Comment: Yes. But EVENTA and EVENTD are triggered by a human.  Think **EVENTA** as an armed system and **EVENTD** a disarmed system. So sometimes you can have EVENTA, followed by one or more  EVENTD. But you'll inevitably find another EVENTA. In this fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/826d03/1, i should get rows 1 to 4 and 6 to 13. In fact, only events when system is armed.
Hope i'm clear

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. yes as those events are triggered by someone, then can double tap on the button and then generate two or more EVENTA or EVENTD at the same second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

- compute running counts of armed events and disarmed events, ordering by date
- compute a ranking order of records for each armed event count, by ordering on the amount of disarmed events

At this point you should note that this ranking value we generated, assumes value 0 when there's not yet an EventD in our armed_event partition. And it gets value 1 when the first EventD is found, till the successive EventD.

So you can just filter accordingly inside a `WHERE` clause, when this ranking value is either 0 or is 1 and event is exactly "EventD".

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(`event`='EVENTA') OVER(ORDER BY datec, id) AS armed_events,
              SUM(`event`='EVENTD') OVER(ORDER BY datec, id) AS disarmed_events
    FROM Table1
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY armed_events ORDER BY disarmed_events) -1 AS rn
    FROM cte
)
SELECT `id`, `datec`, `event` 
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 0 OR (rn = 1 AND `event` = 'EVENTD')
ORDER BY id
```

**Output**:

| id | datec | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-19 12:16:38 | EVENTA |
| 2 | 2022-09-19 12:16:38 | A |
| 3 | 2022-09-19 12:21:08 | B |
| 4 | 2022-09-19 12:21:12 | EVENTD |
| 9 | 2022-09-19 12:25:38 | EVENTA |
| 10 | 2022-09-19 12:25:39 | G |
| 11 | 2022-09-19 12:25:40 | H |
| 12 | 2022-09-19 12:25:48 | I |
| 13 | 2022-09-19 12:27:18 | EVENTD |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n7HYJiEux52tymE9KUo1go/1).

Note: The last `ORDER BY` clause is not necessary. It's there just for visualization purposes.

Comment: And it works indeed (I need a bit time to process that). Thanks a ton for providing me such a good explanation !

Comment: If that can help, I'd suggest observing the partial steps (with some `SELECT * FROM cte`, `SELECT * FROM cte2`), it can give you the full picture of what we're doing.